# Was the battle of Stalingrad "unique" in the annals of history?

Tags: world-war-two, military, nazi-germany, soviet-union, stalingrad

I'm referring to the fact that BOTH sides ordered their troops to fight for the city "to the last man and last round." (Hitler). The Soviet Union's General Vasili Chuikov echoed this by saying "We will defend the city or die in the attempt."

The Soviets were the first to be besieged in Stalingrad in September, 1942. They "survived" by pouring in a steady stream of replacements and reinforcements. But more than 90 percent of the original complement of troops became casualties.

The German 6th Army originally consisted of about 330,000 men. After they were surrounded by seven Soviet armies outside Stalingrad in November, 1942, only 91,000 Germans survived to surrender. Of these, all but 5,000 or so of the starving soldiers soon died in captivity. Making this adjustment, the German death rate was about 98%.

Have there been other instances in history where both sides had armies that were besieged in turn at the same location? And both sides' besieged forces suffered 90+ per cent casualties?

Comment: I focused the question by asking whether there were other battles where BOTH sides met the criterion of having besieged armies, and both besieged forces suffered 90+ percent casualties. The revised question can be answered factually, and not with opinions.

Comment: Stalingrad is in no way a siege from the Russian perspective. It was an assault.

Comment: Did you search for a book on military history that classifies historic battles into categories? Stalingrad might be in there somewhere.

Comment: The description of the Battle of Stalingrad as a "turning point" or unique battle is overstated. It was big. It was important, but there were large systemic changes taking place which were reflected rather than shaped by the battle.

Comment: The Battle of Alesia (52 BC) was politically decisive, had both sides with their backs to the wall, and had both Roman and Gauls besieging each other at exactly the same time - a siege within a siege.

Comment: The claim of 90% casualties is dubious and is obviously not true on a front-wide basis and hardly even demonstrably true on a local level because the Soviets were not really ever under siege during the battle. Suggesting that this 90% figure was true for both sides, and that this says something about the battle, is misguided.

Comment: @AgentOrange: I said "More than 90 percent of the original complement" became casualities. I meant 90 percent of the men present on or about September 13, 1942, the day of the main attack, not 90 percent of the whole front or whole battle. Rodimtsev's 13th Guards Division had 300 survivors from the troops that stormed the city from the Volga, not counting "replacements" recruited locally. Ditto for Zholodov's 37th Guards.

Comment: @TomAu These kinds of casualty rates are not uncommon among front-line troops in prolonged high-intensity combat situations. Look at Verdun, the Somme, or even battles like Sevastopol, Brest-Litovsk, etc., in the USSR, where the fighting got close and ugly. It's not really a unique feature of the Battle of Stalingrad, and it's not really related to any supposed "siege" status. It was a brutal battle, no question, but not unique.

Comment: I believe it is fairly common for besiegers to have to fight off relief forces, but I think the siege of Alesia would count as an instance where both the Romans and the Gallians were besieged. And even at the same time.

Answer (score 16):

Another battle between the Russians and Germans that seems similar is [Battle of Tannenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Tannenberg_%281914%29) during WWI. Out of 206,000 men of the trapped Russian Second Army 78,000 were killed or wounded and 92,000 taken prisoner [1]. However it seems Stalingrad still has the edge on this because both sides had their backs against the wall in 1942, whereas Tannenberg was a bit more one-sided.

[The Battle of Seden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Sedan_%281870%29) destroyed an entire french army (mostly captured, not dead) and lost the Franco Prussian war for them but like Tannenberg was one sided and over quickly. An eastern example of a high casualty battles which outcome decided a large war is [the Battle of Fei River](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Fei_River) (700,000 out of 870,000 deaths on the losing side according to the [Book of Jin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Jin)). But again this was fairly one sided.

So maybe encirclement isn't the important thing and it's about countries stubbornly pouring manpower into the meat-grinder of an "un-loseable" war of attrition. The Western Front of WWI is a great example (lots of decimated units here[2]). [Verdun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Verdun) being a particularly horrific fight over some hilly ground near Verdun-sur-Meuse. Loss at Verdun might have might have lost the war for the Allies, but didn't losw it (not immediately anyway) for Germany. Perhaps Stalingrad was more decisive than Verdun in particular, but if you compare it to the western front in general there are a lot of similarities.

As far as other important battles with horrible casualty rates go the [Battle of Antietam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Antietam) and percentagewise more lethal [Battle of Stones River](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Stones_River) are good American examples. [Leipzig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Leipzig) is a good example before industrialised warfare.

So while there are lots of examples of desperate fighting, encirclement and awful causalities. I would agree that given the intense struggle on both sides and it's decisive role in the Great Patriotic War (that's WW2) Stalingrad was fairly unique, with the western front in WW1 being the strongest contender in my mind.

[1] Source: Sweetman, John (2004), Tannenberg 1914 (1st ed.), London: Cassell, ISBN 978-0-304-35635-5 p158

[2]  Somme example: the 1st Newfoundland Regiment suffered 91% casualties in the Somme, 801 men, 500 dead, 233 wounded, which puts it in second place to the 10th Battalion West Yorkshire on the same day but I can't find those numbers

[PS] Thought I would mention ambushes like the [The Battle of Salsu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Salsu) (302,300 out of 305,000) or ['Quintilius Varus, give me back my legions!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Teutoburg_Forest), but I don't think they can be compared to Stalingrad.

Comment: Good try, but I wasn't really talking about "one-sided" battles. My question was about battles where BOTH sides were ready to sacrifice large percentages (more than 50%) of their troops.

Comment: skip the first two paragraphs then.

Answer (score 4):

You usually don't get casualties that goes so high; one side or the other will have the sense to realise that the battle is lost and retreat. When they can't, their losses will ramp up while the winner's will stay relatively modest.

One battle with very high losses on both sides is the Dano-Swedish [Battle of Lund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Lund). However, that was not due to the generals grinding the units down; it was a very confused affair where the Swedish cavalry broke of to chase the Danish cavalry, while the Swedish infantry was very hard pressed and would have lost if the cavalry had not returned. In the end, the casualty rates for both armies where over 50 % (including wounded and prisoners of war). It has been noted as one of the bloodiest pitched battles ever.